# Creating a Firebase API that makes Third-party API Requests

Tags: firebase

I'm exploring the option of using Firebase to create an API, but it's not clear whether I can use the API to make third-party API requests.

For example, I'd like to use Firebase to query an API service I've already developed. Essentially use Firebase as a middleware.

Comment: This question is too vague to answer. Please do clarify :)

Comment: Firebase is the wrong tool for that job.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume you are referring to Firebase Functions. They can make calls ([outside network requests as they call them](https://firebase.google.com/pricing/)) when you are on the Flame or the Blaze plan, but not on the spark plan.

> Firebase projects on the Spark plan can make only outbound requests to Google APIs. Requests to third-party APIs fail with an error. For more information about upgrading your project, see Pricing.

### Update

For further information regarding the specifics of this question: [Integrating with 3rd party APIs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/use-cases#integrate_with_third-party_services_and_apis)

Comment: Thanks Chris! Your comment lead to this... https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/use-cases#integrate_with_third-party_services_and_apis

Comment: Perfect, I will add that to my answer